Where in the specification is this way of macro expansion avoidance defined?
Given the following code:
#include <limits>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
}

I can avoid the preprocessor macro expansion of max() from Windows.h using additional parentheses:
#include <limits>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    (std::numeric_limits<double>::max)();
}

Does this "feature" have a name? Where in the C++ specification is this "feature" defined? I'd like to know more about it. I searched for "function-like macro", but didn't find relevant entries on this way of avoiding macro expansion.
If version matters, then C++14, but if the principle didn't change, you can also direct me to newer version of the standard.

Well, isn't it clear that the latter code does not have a max() text which could be replaced with the macro definition? See 'Function-like macros' from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Well, as mentioned you have #define max(A, B)  and when you use parentheses  to call max it's a function call from std (with no ADL, but it doesn't matter)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai what do you mean? Macro(functional macro or whatever it called) expects max + ( but found max + ), so no replacement happened

@ruohola: well, I get the idea, and I like that it works, but obviously the preprocessor also ignores ::

We should always #define NOMINMAX before #include <Windows.h> to avoid this issue.

By the way, if you want to use std::max instead of macro max, you can use std::max<int>, which also avoids macro expansion.

Closed as s duplicate. See my answer to the duplicate question.

I disagree on the dup. OP's question is not "how to avoid the macro expansion?", but rather "why this trick work?". @ThomasWeller maybe tag your question with [tag:language-lawyer] to confirm.

@YSC -- I agree with your disagreement. Repened.

Added the language-lawyer tag, since the OP explicitly asked "Where in the C++ specification ...".

This is defined by the C++ language. A function-like macro is replaced by its definition only if the non-whitespace character following its name is a (.
In phase 4 of the translation ("compilation"):

[lex.phases]/4
Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and _Pragma unary operator expressions are executed.

The definition and rules regarding a preprocessing directive is relevant:

[cpp.replace.general]/12
A preprocessing directive of the form
# define identifier lparen identifier-list_opt) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line

defines a function-like macro with parameters, whose use is similar syntactically to a function call. The parameters are specified by the optional list of identifiers. Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name followed by a ( as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition (an invocation of the macro). The replaced sequence of preprocessing tokens is terminated by the matching ) preprocessing token, skipping intervening matched pairs of left and right parenthesis preprocessing tokens. Within the sequence of preprocessing tokens making up an invocation of a function-like macro, new-line is considered a normal whitespace character.



Where in the specification is this way of macro expansion avoidance defined?

The standard  specifies when the function-like macro will be used which is when the macro name is followed by () and optional arguments.  As a result we do get when it will not be applied(which is when the () are not used as in your second example).
From cpp.replace.general:

A preprocessing directive of the form
# define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line

defines a function-like macro with parameters, whose use is similar syntactically to a function call.
The parameters are specified by the optional list of identifiers.
Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name followed by a ( as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition (an invocation of the macro).
The replaced sequence of preprocessing tokens is terminated by the matching ) preprocessing token, skipping intervening matched pairs of left and right parenthesis preprocessing tokens.
Within the sequence of preprocessing tokens making up an invocation of a function-like macro, new-line is considered a normal whitespace character.

(emphasis mine)
Note the emphasis on "macro name followed by...".
In your second example, the macro name max is not followed by ( and so in the second case we won't get the macro use.
